# Rails 4 has_many :through relationship: destroy parent model instance when child model instance count reaches 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-view-controller, has-many-through

In our Rails 4 app, there are four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Here are the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :total_calendar_count
      t.integer :owned_calendar_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
        t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
        t.date :date
        t.time :time
        t.string :focus
        t.string :format
        t.string :blog_title
        t.text :long_copy
        t.text :short_copy
        t.string :link
        t.string :hashtag
        t.string :media
        t.float :promotion
        t.string :target
        t.integer :approval
        t.text :comment

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Each time a `user` quits a `calendar`, meaning we `destroy` the corresponding `administration`, we want to make sure that the following happens:

- We check if there are other `administrations` for the same `calendar`.
- If there are, we do nothing (the user is simply redirected to his dashboard).
- But if there aren't any more (because the user was the last one to quit the calendar for example), then we want to destroy the calendar as well.
- This should automatically destroy all the posts belonging to this calendar, thanks to the `has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy` line in our `Calendar` model, but we guess it would not hurt to check that too.

We are thinking of achieving this through a `private` `clear_calendar` method in the `Calendar` model, that we would use as an after_destroy callback in the `Administrations` controller:

```
private

  def clear_calendar
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    unless @calendar.administration.exists?
      @calendar.destroy
    end
  end
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: That looks like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: Only thing I'd suggest is doing it out-of-band using something like Sidekiq, unless it's important they get removed immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. We are not familiar with Sidekiq, and the integration to our app may be a bit complicated given our rookie skillset, but we will take a look at it for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very sensible approach, and the whole world is happy that you didn't place this logic in a controller action.

One thing to note: by placing this logic in your `Calendar` model, you're necessarily binding `Calendar` and `Administration` together. Perhaps you find that to be ok at this point in time, but a truly object-oriented program, instead of asking another model if it exists, would instead tell a model *what* it wants, instead of *how* it wants it done (e.g. delete `self` if this association doesn't exist).

I would recommend placing this logic in a PORO--perhaps a service--that removes unnecessary coupling from your database-backed objects. Perhaps that'd look something like so:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base

...

private

  def clear_calendar
    ParentDestructionService.new(self)
  end

end


class ParentDestructionService
  def initialize(parent)
    @parent = parent
  end

  .....logic goes here.....
end
```

This way, not only do you truly separate a *how* process from a class that shouldn't care about `Administration`, but you now have the capabilities to either stick this in a Sidekiq process, or simply thread it off. Either way, you're way more flexible. Now in the future, you'll be able to send ANY parent through that service, and things will work as intended.

Comment: Thank you very much. By chance, could you point us to any resource that outlines your approach, including an explanation what a PORO is? Sorry, this seems more advanced than we are.

Comment: Sure! A PORO is a "plain old Ruby object," meaning it doesn't adhere to any Rails conventions—it just exists to work. If you've never read "Practical Object-Oriented Design in Rails" by Sandi Metz, it's the de facto book on object-oriented Ruby and will change your life ;)

Comment: You bet. Feel free to up vote/accept if you see fit.